# How to add INSPINIA bootstrap to Ember application

Tags: css, asp.net, ember.js, ember-cli

New user to 3rd party bootstrap templates for Ember and need help.

I purchased the [INSPINIA](https://wrapbootstrap.com/theme/inspinia-responsive-admin-theme-WB0R5L90S) admin template from www.wrapbootstrap.com. The download comes with multiple pre-created projects with INSPINIA built in (e.g., Angular, Rails, etc.) but not for Ember. I reached out to the creator to see if they could include a project for Ember and they said no.

So, I am curious, does anyone know how to add INSPINIA to an Ember web application? Is it as simple as `ember install bootstrap` and then copy the *.css file? Note: the INSPINIA template comes with way more files than just a *.css, and I am using ASP.NET CORE 2.2 for the web API.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I did the same thing a few years ago, I bought the theme just for the themed css. I used their `less` and integrated that into my existing `ember` build. Nowadays I'd use the `scss` but it's unimportant.

What is important is understanding that bootstrap js components will not *simply* work in the context of your `ember` application. If you want callbacks, events, binding, etc to exist in the context of `ember` (ie within `ember`'s runloop and lifecycle), you will need to wrap each individual component. Luckily, [ember-boostrap](https://www.ember-bootstrap.com) does exactly that for you. This addon provides the easiest way for you to pull in your `bootstrap` scss. This addon also does not use bootstrap's `js`, but rather is a full implementation of the bootstrap component's in a way that is ember-aware.

> ember-bootstrap deliberately excludes bootstrap.js
>   because the jQuery and Ember ways of control flow and animation
>   sometimes don't play well together, causing unpredictable results.
>   This is the main motivation behind ember-bootstrap. It is possible to
>   import bootstrap.js from bower_components or the vendor folder. This
>   is NOT recommended or supported, and you will be on your own. You have
>   been warned!

Once you've gotten the `scss` preprocessing properly set up in your `ember-cli-build.js` file, you should be able to use their markup more or less directly. You will need to have some understanding, though, of when you're encountering bootstrap markup (stuff with data classes that will be handled by bootstrap's js). In moments like that, you simply use `ember-bootstrap` components instead

Comment: Wow, this is great. Thank you for the background detail. By any chance, do you have some online material that provides a step-by-step 'How To'?