# How do I install bootstrap 4 template to Ember web project?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ember.js, bootstrap-4, ember-cli

This is a continuation of another post I have posted: [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56102043/how-to-add-inspinia-bootstrap-to-ember-application)

I have downloaded the [INSPINIA](https://wrapbootstrap.com/theme/inspinia-responsive-admin-theme-WB0R5L90S) admin theme, which is based off twitter bootstrap. It contains pre-created projects for most web-ui frameworks, except Ember. Steps taken so far:

1. Installed ember-boostrap
2. Installed SASS pre-processor
3. Copied the *.scss files into the app\styles folder
4. The app.scss file looks as follows:

**app\styles\app.scss**

```
@import "ember-bootstrap/bootstrap";

@import "style";
```

5. The Ember-Cli-Build.js file is as follows:

**Ember-Cli-Build.js**

```
'use strict';

const EmberApp = require('ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app');

module.exports = function(defaults) {
  let app = new EmberApp(defaults, {
    'ember-bootstrap': {
      'bootstrapVersion': 4,
      'importBootstrapFont': false,
      'importBootstrapCSS': false
    }
  });
  return app.toTree();
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The workflow order is important. From [ember-boostrap's "Using CSS preprocessors" section](https://www.ember-bootstrap.com/#/getting-started/assets)

> Important note: this only works when you have the CSS preprocessor
>   addon installed before installing ember-bootstrap itself. If that is
>   not the case, make sure to run the default install blueprint after
>   installing the preprocessor addon: ember generate ember-bootstrap!
>   This will execute the necessary setup steps as described above.

According to what you posted here, you installed the sass preprocessor afterwards. You can look [inside the addon's blueprint](https://github.com/kaliber5/ember-bootstrap/blob/5acaa52e321ab8cb92ffc33dd22db92d5e9879b2/blueprints/ember-bootstrap/index.js) to understand how it's determining what dependencies to use. Basically the code here is invoked after running `ember install <some-addon>`. If you look at the code, you'll see conditional code based on whether you have certain packages already installed and whether you have preprocessors.

In your case, you should have ended up with `bootstrap` in your `npm` dependencies. Check your `package.json` as well as your `node_modules` to see if this is installed.

But to help you further, here's exactly what I just did to create a new project using a random theme `sb-admin-2` from [startbootstrap.com](https://startbootstrap.com/themes/sb-admin-2/)

1. `ember new bootstrap-example --yarn`
2. `ember install ember-cli-sass` (I then removed `app.css`)
3. `ember install ember-bootstrap`

   - its worth noting that this step added `@import "ember-bootstrap/bootstrap";` automatically to my `app.scss` file.
4. copied the whole `scss` dir containing all scss files from said project into `vendor/sb-admin-2/scss`
5. Cleaned up the imports inside the main `sb-admin-2.scss` since it contained references to its own path to `bootstrap.scss`
6. added this `scss` dir to my `ember-cli-build.js` `sassOptions` `includePaths` array:

   ```
   sassOptions: {
     includePaths: [
       'vendor/sb-admin-2/scss',
     ]
   }
   ```
7. Added reference for the sb-admin-2 template to **/app/styles/app.scss** for: `@import "sb-admin-2.scss";`
8. Copy and pasted their login markup (inside of the body) into my some route template (in my case the `application.hbs` template b/c this isn't a real project).

   - I needed to then add a class to the body so I did this:

     ```
     activate(){
        this._super(...arguments);
        document.body.classList.add('bg-gradient-primary');
     }
     ```

You can view the project on my [github](https://github.com/mistahenry/ember-sb-admin-2-demo). Good luck :)

Comment: You sir are a true gentleman and a scholar. The step-by-step walk through and project on GitHub are exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you aware of any projects on Git or web resources that demonstrate how to implement bootstrap frameworks in Ember? I took the Embercasts tutorial that explains how to build an API JSON web app, but it really doesn't discuss how to implement bootstrap frameworks. I can post another question.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "implement bootstrap frameworks". probably best to open another question or to ask in the ember discord