# How to get css animations working in Ember

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, ember.js, bootstrap-4, ember-cli

Note: I am using the INSPINIA administrative theme and this question is an extension of the following question: [How do I install bootstrap 4 template to Ember web project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56179210/how-do-i-install-bootstrap-4-template-to-ember-web-project)

How do I get css animations working in Ember?

I am attempting to get the collapse-able sidebar navigation menu working (see the INSPINIA link [here](http://webapplayers.com/inspinia_admin-v2.9.2/index.html)). **Currently, I do not see the arrow and the menu is displayed only in expanded form in the `<ul class="nav nav-second-level">...</ul>` block of code.**

In looking at the sample projects and `View Source` page, there appear to be a lot of add-ons that INSPINIA uses. Do I need to install all of them? Or, do I just need jQuery?

Here is the code for my handlebar file in question.

```
<nav class="navbar-default navbar-static-side" role="navigation">
    <div class="sidebar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav metismenu" id="side-menu">
            {{#if session.isAuthenticated}}
                <li class="active"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-th-large"></i> <span class="nav-label">Client</span> <span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                    <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                        <li><a href="#">Update Information</a></li>
                        <li>{{#link-to "clients.change-password"}}Change Password{{/link-to}}</li>
                        <li><a href="#" onclick={{action "logout"}}>Logout</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            {{else}}
                <li>{{#link-to "clients.login"}}Login{{/link-to}}</li>
                <li>{{#link-to "clients.register"}}Register{{/link-to}}</li>
            {{/if}}

            <li>{{#link-to "misc.about"}}About{{/link-to}}</li>
            <li>{{#link-to "misc.contactus"}}Contact Us{{/link-to}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: @mistahenry any ideas?

Comment: I don't know much about bootstrap, but you will likely need some JS to add and remove the active classes for the dropdown.

Comment: @nullvoxpopuli Do you know how to do that or what web resources I can check?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using [Liquid Fire](https://ember-animation.github.io/liquid-fire/).

> Liquid Fire is a toolkit for managing animated transitions in an Ember application.

You can use the `transition.js` file to manage the duration, direction, timing etc. of CSS transitions in your app.

You may use [Ember Animated](https://ember-animation.github.io/ember-animated/) if you need more control over your animations.

Comment: this is overkill if trying to just use css animations

Comment: Liquid Fire does not appear to be the solution